# Set default value of 'Default External Access' to Private for new Objects

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule

In Sharing setting, is there any way we can set the default value of '**Default External Access**' to Private for new Objects?

Like, whenever an Object comes in, the '**Default External Access**' should set to **Private**.

Comment: [External Objects](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=external_object_define.htm&type=5) and [Default External Access](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_owd_external_setting.htm&type=5) are not related. What is your exact question here, can you clarify?

Comment: Is there a way to set 'Default External Access' to private by default when an object is created?

Comment: presumably this is to help avoid being flagged by SFDC Health Check as a Critical item